# PHP Post Not Working On Textarea

Tags: php, forms, post

I have read many posts here about this issue but it doesn't help me. I have a form but the textarea doesnt post. Here is my form:

```
<form action="php/contact.php" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="name_field" placeholder="Name" required>
        </br>
            <input type="email" name="email_field" placeholder="Email" required>
        </br>
            <input type="text" name="subject_field" placeholder="Subject">
        </br>
            <textarea class="message_area" name="message_textarea" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
        </br>
            <button class="contact_form_button" type="submit">SEND</button>
        </form>
```

And my PHP:

```
    <?php
$field_name = $_POST['name_field'];
$field_email = $_POST['email_field'];
$field_subject = $_POST['subject_field'];
$field_message = htmlentities($_POST['message_textarea']);

echo $field_message;
?>
```

It works for the other inputs but not the message. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's odd. I don't see any errors. What does `print_r($_POST);` give you?

Comment: Working Fine for me.

Comment: Not see any errors here

Comment: What are you putting inside `textarea`? I hope you have not put a character which is resulting in a whitespace, line break etc. Does it show any output without htmlentities()?

Comment: I have tried absolutely everything, with and without. I cannot find a problem. I do see it with print_r though. Strange. Any reason why. I also tried to email it, but it shows blank aswell. Any suggestions?